# Run app on windows authentication mode without the credentials popup

Tags: authentication, iis, httprequest, digest-authentication

My application should run on Windows authentication mode and in the app I should got the log in name of the user.
I read the name from the Request

```
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

But when publish on IIS all user got the credential popup window on each page redirect So which mode could handle it and solve this issue !

Enable the Digest authentication or windows or what on my iis ?

Comment: As far as I know, Internet Explorer is the only browser that will forward user credentials to your application. See this blog post for details: https://sysadminspot.com/windows/google-chrome-and-ntlm-auto-logon-using-windows-authentication/

Comment: And The target browser is IE so I have t handle this case on it !